How to resize image by ratio, like 4:3 or 1:1, using spatie media library
I am using spatie media library in my Laravel project.
Now I want to make two different image thumbnail or conversion. Ratio of first one is 1:1 and another one is 4:3.
Like if I upload an image dimension with 1600x2000 pixel, my first thumbnail should be 1600x1600 pixel and second one will be 1600x900.
Please give me some solution...
I register media collection in my Product Model, but it's not working
public function registerMediaCollections(): void
{
  $this->addMediaCollection('featured-image')
  ->singleFile()
  ->registerMediaConversions( function( Media $media ){
    $this->addMediaConversion('square')
        ->width(400)
        ->height(400)
        ->nonQueued();
    $this->addMediaConversion('card')
        ->width(400)
        ->height(300)
        ->nonQueued();
  });
  
}


When you're working with image uploads in Laravel using Spatie Media Library, getting precise image thumbnails can be a bit tricky. What you want is to take an uploaded image and create two specific thumbnail versions:
a perfect square thumbnail
a wider, more rectangular thumbnail with a 4:3 aspect ratio
`
public function registerMediaCollections(): void
{
    $this->addMediaCollection('featured-image')
    ->singleFile()
    ->registerMediaConversions(function(Media $media) {
        // 1:1 Square Conversion (Crop to square)
        $this->addMediaConversion('square')
            ->fit(Manipulations::FIT_CROP, 1600, 1600)
            ->width(1600)
            ->height(1600)
            ->nonQueued();

        // 4:3 Conversion (Crop to 4:3 ratio)
        $this->addMediaConversion('card')
            ->fit(Manipulations::FIT_CROP, 1600, 900)
            ->width(1600)
            ->height(900)
            ->nonQueued();
    });
}`

So when you upload an image like a 1600x2000 pixel photo:
the square thumbnail will become a perfect 1600x1600 pixel image
the card/rectangular thumbnail will become a 1600x900 pixel image
`// To get the square thumbnail URL
$squareThumb = $product->getFirstMediaUrl('featured-image', 'square');

// To get the 4:3 rectangular thumbnail URL
$cardThumb = $product->getFirstMediaUrl('featured-image', 'card');`

